# OOP inheritance, how to get variable of parent type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, initialization

i have this code so far:

```
class vehicle:
    def __init__(self, numWheels, listWeightOfItem):
        self.numWheels = numWheels
        self.listWeightOfItem = listWeightOfItem

class car(vehicle):
    def __init__(self, numWheels, listWeightOfItem, listWeightPeople):
        vehicle.__init__(self, numWheels, listOfWeightItem)
        self.listWeightPeople = listWeightPeople
```

Car is going to inherit from vehicle.
Car is supposed to have a trailer of type vehicle and I do not know how to put this into code. I thought about creating a class variable but I do not think that it makes sense, and how do i make sure the trailer is of type vehicle and not car?

Comment: You can make more classes that are a subclass of one

Comment: you can have for example class trailer(vehicle)

Comment: By the way, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and class names the `CamelCase` one.

Answer (score 0):

> Car is going to inherit from vehicle. Car is supposed to have a trailer of type vehicle and I do not know how to put this into code. I thought about creating a class variable but I do not think that it makes sense, and how do i make sure the trailer is of type vehicle and not car?

Why a class variable and not an instance variable?

> how do i make sure the trailer is of type vehicle and not car?

Why would there be any risk related to that?

---

If I understand the situation correctly, you can do something like this:

```py
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, num_wheels: int, list_weight_item: float) -> None:
        self.num_wheels = num_wheels
        self.list_weight_item = list_weight_item

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Vehicle(num_wheels={self.num_wheels}, " \
               f"list_weight_item={self.list_weight_item})"


class Trailer(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, num_wheels: int, list_weight_item: float, cargo_type: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(num_wheels, list_weight_item)
        self.cargo_type = cargo_type

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Trailer(num_wheels={self.num_wheels}, " \
               f"list_weight_item={self.list_weight_item}, " \
               f"cargo_type={self.cargo_type})"


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, num_wheels: int, list_weight_item: float, list_weight_people: float,
                 trailer: Trailer = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(num_wheels, list_weight_item)
        self.list_weight_people = list_weight_people
        self.trailer = trailer

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Car(num_wheels={self.num_wheels}, " \
               f"list_weight_item={self.list_weight_item}, " \
               f"list_weight_people={self.list_weight_people}, " \
               f"trailer={self.trailer})"


t_1 = Vehicle(2, 100)
t_2 = Trailer(num_wheels=2, list_weight_item=1000, cargo_type='car')
t_3 = Car(num_wheels=4, list_weight_item=2000, list_weight_people=200, trailer=t_2)
t_4 = Car(num_wheels=4, list_weight_item=2500, list_weight_people=300)

print(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just make another class of subclass vehicle. You didn't specify what you wanted trailed to have in it so I just left it empty for you to fill.

```
class vehicle:
    def __init__(self, numWheels, listWeightOfItem):
        self.numWheels = numWheels
        self.listWeightOfItem = listWeightOfItem

class car(vehicle):
    def __init__(self, numWheels, listWeightOfItem, listWeightPeople):
        vehicle.__init__(self, numWheels, listOfWeightItem)
        self.listWeightPeople = listWeightPeople

class trailer(vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Comment: but isn't trailer going to be of type trailer then and not of type vehicle?

Comment: No it will not be

Comment: it is subclass vehicle